# Log4j log lost(not print to console) after Main Thread Finished

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm using Spring Boot with Log4j with massive parallel computing.

I've using consoleappender to show log message to sysout.

I'm not setting async log4j, so LogManager.shutdown is not allow in this case.

After the program finished successfully, some log were lost(not showed in the console), below is some code/config snippet.

```
public class TestClass() {

    Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TestClass.class);

    main() {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

        for(large amount) {

            executorService.submit(() -> {
                LOGGER.info(".....")        // lots of log message inside each task
            });

        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        // Thread.sleep(10000) // If main thread sleep for a few seconds, all the log will show in the console.
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO"  monitorInterval="5" package="...">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="application.name">...</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">  
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd@HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} ${application.name} %X{X-B3-TraceId} - %msg%n" charset="UTF-8" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="..." level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My questions are:

1. Is log4j logger daemon thread for both sync/async? (If yes, can i set it to non-daemon thread?)
2. How to let my main thread wait util all the log are successfully printed to the console?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did you configure Log4j? Log4j2 oder Log4j 1?

Comment: I'm using Log4j2, have add the config snippet to the post.

Comment: According to Log4j2 documentation delivery of log statements to console is not guaranteed

Comment: Could you please give me the official link page for the reference? Thanks

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html

Comment: @SimonMartinelli That doesn't mean what you are implying. When writing to stdout in a docker container events could be lost because they could be in transit between all the moving parts. When writing to the console in a standalone app the only reason messages wouldn't appear is if they were written to a buffer and it wasn't flushed. But generally the console doesn't buffer, which has a lot to do with why it is so slow.